# scanf(" %[^\n]", s); then how to strcmp in C?

Tags: c, scanf, strcmp

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", in);
```

then for example , i input Knock Knock and hit enter

but my code block inside

```
if (strcmp ("Knock Knock",out)==0)
```

does not work

please instruct me ,thanks a lot!

```
char in[80],out[80];

void input(){
    printf("Client: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",in);

    fp=fopen("test","w");
    if (!fp) return ;
    fputs(in,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

fp=fopen("test","r");
    fgets(out,81,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("test","w");
    if (strcmp ("Knock Knock",out)==0)
        fputs("Server: Who is there?\n",fp);
```

Comment: Do you realize you read the data into `s` but tried to compare to `out`?

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` works with Linux line breaks. If you are working in Windows, you may need to have `"%[^\r\n]"` as format specifier for `scanf`.

Comment: @mizo: Windows does not support regular expressions inside `scanf` format strings, so it's not going to work on Windows at all.

Comment: I am developing this code in linux

Comment: @Billy: that depends on library implementation, not operating system. This works fine in MinGW, for example. It has some extensions over `MSVCRT` in `libmingwex`.

Comment: @mizo: Given that MinGW doesn't actually implement the full C++ standard, much less the entire Windows API, I find it hard to classify it as a "windows compiler" as MSVC++ or ICC are. Sure, that *particular* function is part of a library, but on the other hand so is *everything* in the C standard library.

Answer (score 4):

First off, the layout of the code is very confusing, and as it stands, it would never compile.  You have a function `input()` that you never seem to call, and you leave code outside the function that should be inside another function, or better yet, all of it should be contained inside a `main()` function so that it can be executed.  Here is a cleaned up example for what you're wanting to-do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char in[80],out[80];

int main()
{
    printf("Client: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",in);  //you really should use fgets() here

    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return 1;
    }

    fputs(in,fp);
    fputs("\n",fp);
    fclose(fp);


    fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return 1;
    }

    fgets(out,80,fp);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("test.txt","a+");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return 1;
    }

    if (strcmp ("Knock Knock\n",out)==0)
        fputs("Server: Who is there?\n",fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Some important notes:

1) `fp` has a file-type `FILE*`, since that is the return of `fopen()`, but you never declare it as such.  So this would never compile with that error.

2) Every time you open a file with the `w` flag, it erases the entire contents of the file.  So if you were intending on appending to the file to have a history of what your output from your program was, you need to use the `a+` flag when calling `fopen()`

3) It would be nice to have some type of error print-out if you failed to open the file rather than scratching your head at why "test.txt" is empty after the program takes the input from `stdin`.  Also if you're going to keep re-opening the file, check for a NULL each time since you're going to get unpredictable results from trying to work with a NULL file pointer (most likely a crash).

4) `scanf()` can result in nasty buffer over-runs from user-input (or malicious user input) ... use `fgets()` with `stdin` to a known-length buffer instead.

You should be able to compile this code now and run it.  Works for me with gcc 4.4.3 on Ubuntu.  After running, your "test.txt" file should look like:

```
Knock Knock
Server: Who is there?
```